# Flashback gnome doesn't work on 14.04

Tags: compiz, login, metacity

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 a while back and decided to try out the Gnome flashback option. I used the software center to get it installed and after logging out I have the two extra options (metacity and compiz). However when I log in using these I don't get anything on my desktop except for the background picture. I can use the right click to get to system settings (via all settings after clicking 'change background'), but I do not see an option to manually start the panel or anything else. Also, I cannot logout, shut down or do anything else than use a hard power down, restart the computer and then login to unity which still works perfectly fine. Anyone have any clues why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall it in software center. 
Open terminal and type :
`sudo apt-get install gnome-panel` It will ask for password. When typing : password won't show, but you're typing it!

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before as well. No luck. I just found a similar question on here and the answer on that one worked. While in unity, open a terminal window and use the command: cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-panel.desktop ~/.config/autostart/ Then restart and it works. Thank you for your reply though. Appreciate it.